# Watch a page in gitlab wiki

Tags: notifications, wiki, gitlab

How can I watch a page in gitlab wiki and receive notifications every time someone edit/modify the page. I already watch the project and receive notifications for commits, comments etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answer my own question after posting in Gital user group.

It is not possible to watch a page in Gitlab wiki. See link below

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gitlabhq/v887P52tMXI/MqaCWztc7sAJ

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem recently. Not receiving alerts was not an option in our case, so I ended up writing an external program that can generically watch git repositories for commit changes and send emails. Here's the project: https://github.com/datamachines/gitwatch